# Program in C++ doesn't stop on if(scanf()==EOF)break;

Tags: c++, windows

My program in C++ doesn't stop on `if(scanf()==EOF)break;`, below is sketch of my program, for example input:

```
X XjhgXjhX
```

gives output:

```
jhgjh
```

that is - it prints all characters except `X`, but it doesn't stop on `Ctrl+Z`.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[100]={0},znak,forbd;
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(true)
    {
        i=0;
        j=0;

        if(scanf("%c",&forbd)==EOF)
            break;

        if(scanf("%c",&znak)==EOF)
            break;

        while(znak!='\n')
        {
            if(forbd!=znak && znak!=' ')
            {
                str[i]=znak;
                i++;
                //cout<<i<<"\n";
            }

            if(scanf("%c",&znak)==EOF)
                break;
        }

        while(j<i)
        {
            printf("%c",str[j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("%c",'\n');
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I don't want to use `cin`, because of trouble with reading `\n`.

Comment: I think you should rather ask about solving your problem with `cin` instead.

Comment: @moooeeeep but what about `cin` and `\n` issue then ? I prefer `scanf` because it's really faster.

Comment: @Qbik: What is the issue with cin and `\n`? For the above code I doubt you would see any difference in performance. C++ streams are slower for 2 reasons 1) They bind to stdin/stdout (unbind them and it becomes quicker) 2) The formatted read on streams do a lot more work with locals (so you pay for the work). If you don't care about that then don;t use formatted reads. They are still slightly slower but not what I would call significant enough to worry about.

Comment: @Loki `scanf` also does work with locales. I don’t think `cin` is any slower. In fact, I’d expect it to be faster since it doesn’t need to parse its formatting arguments at runtime. Using `scanf` for performance reasons is simply idiotic.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I totally agree. But there is always somebody that wants to argue about it (and I don't care). So adding the last line pacifies them. As far as I can tell there is no *significant* performance differences and the added type safety is more than enough compensation.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph on SPOJ codes with `iostream` are often too slow

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-D? (if this is a UniClone)?

Comment: @Qbik I’m fairly certain that this is caused by incompetence rather than iostream (most likely culprit: sync with stdio). There are plenty of benchmarks which demonstrate that their performance is on par.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I'm too novice too judge it, but I believe you, I was reading a few benchmarks

Comment: The above code, after fixing the syntax errors, [works just fine for me](http://ideone.com/YsYlYJ). Maybe it's a Windows thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig it's pure XP

Comment: Found it: article that examines stdin Vs std::cin shows no difference as long as you unbind them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9747716/14065

Comment: I am still interested to know what the issue with '\n' is?

Comment: The considering you never read more than one char, why not just use `fgetc(stdin)` ?

Comment: @Rob it still doesn't work for me

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean? What, precisely, do you type? What, precisely, do you observe?

Comment: @Rob it still doesn't stop on `Ctrl+Z`

Comment: What does 'it still doesn't stop' mean? Key-by-key, what do you type? What do you see? How do you conclude that it doesn't stop?

Comment: @Rob a asa`enter` `ctrl+z`it doesn't break main `while` loop.

Comment: I believe that you are missing one keystroke. IIRC, in order to send an EOF to a Windows console program, you have to type `enter`, `ctrl+z`, `enter`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'm going to use `iostream` instead of `cstdio` with code `if(cin.peek()=='\n')break;` detecting end of line, this solves issue.

Answer (score 0):

scanf reads from [stdin reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/?kw=stdin) witch:

> stdin is known to not refer to an interactive device, the stream is fully buffered. Otherwise, it is library-dependent whether the stream is line buffered or not buffered by default (see setvbuf).

Usually, stdin is line buffered and you need to type '\n' to read.

From an correlated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421871/1778115) you can find solutions for this type use case of character reading.